# add a class to some options in the dropdownlist using options binding in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am reading in options json coming from a call in my controller.  I am binding the observable array to my dropdownlist and it works great.  But I want to add a class to some of the options in the list based on one of the variables coming down in the json.
Here is my HTML select:

```
<select data-bind="value: sellerID, options: $root.sellers, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', optionsCaption: ' -- select a student --', disable: disableSeller" class="form-control" id="sellerSelect" name="sellerId"></select>
```

And here is my Knockout:

Init:

```
var groups = @Html.Raw( Json.Encode(ViewBag.GroupDetail.SellerGroup) );
sellerViewModel = new SellerViewModel(groups, "", 10);
ko.applyBindings(sellerViewModel, $("#studentInfo")[0]);
```

Setting the options list:

```
$(data.sellers).each(function(index, element) {
  sellerViewModel.sellers.push({Text: element.lastName + ", " + element.firstName, Value: element.sellerId})
});
```

In that last chunk of code, `element` has a variable called `dateVerify`.  If `dateVerify` is not null, I want to add a class to that option in the select list, so i can color it a different color.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the most elegant way, but according to the knockout [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), there is an `optionsAfterRender` callback that allows you to perform custom actions after an option is added. You could use jQuery / vanilla JS / whatever to then add the desired class.

```
optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) {
    if(!item.dateVerify) {
        $(option).addClass("some-class");
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to modify this to fit your code more exactly, but I think this is what you're looking for.